# How can I access a sub-collection firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
getLikeInfo() {
  this.firestore.getDocument({
    path: ['Posts', this.postData.postId],
    onComplete: (result) => {
      let userDocument = result.data();
      this.userLikeId = userDocument!['creatorId'];
    },
  });
```

[image: this is the structure of my firestore database]

I want access to the sub collection "PostLinks". I tried more and more thing, but none work. Can someone explain me how I can access on a sub collection?

Comment: The subcollection `PostLinks` or the subcollection `PostLikes`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what framework/library your `this.firestore` comes from, but I think you're looking for something like:

```
this.firestore.getDocuments({
  path: ['Posts', this.postData.postId, 'PostLikes'],
  ...
```

Comment: i try this but not work i get an error message  in chrome console uncaught (in Promise): "Not a valid path to a document"

Comment: You might have missed that I changed the method call to `getDocuments` (plural, with an extra `s`) at the end, since you're reading an entire collection.

Comment: oh thx man , i will try today ^^